# Отказ от макросов в пользу конструкций языка

Tags: c++

Задание заключается в следующем:

> Приведите примеры отказа от макросов-объектов и макросов-функций в
>   пользу конструкций языка, не связанных с этапом предварительной
>   обработки.

Ума не приложу, каков тут может быть ответ.

Comment: `#define sqr(x) x*x` - плохо. `template <class T> inline auto sqr(T x) -> decltype(x*x) { return x*x; }` - хорошо. Почему? `sqr(i++);`. А в шаблон еще и проверку на типы можно добавить.

Comment: Пример ясен, благодарю!

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/197266/

Answer (score 2):

Макросы-функции

```
#define summ(x, y) (x)+(y)
```

Следует заменить на встраиваемые шаблонные функции

```
template<class T>
inline T summ(const T &x, const T &y){
    return x + y;
}
```

Макросы-константы

```
#define c 299792458.0
```

Следует заменить на константы

```
const double c = 299792458.0;
```